# How to browse Applescript object "DOM" for a given object?

Tags: applescript

Given an object in Applescript (i.e. I have an Object Specifier to it), how do I find out what all accessible properties(?) that it has are?  I am not sure that `properties` is the right word here, and part of my question is what the correct vocabulary is; I will illustrate what I mean with the following example.

For instance:

Using the following Object Specifier, `tell application "System Events" to get process "TextEdit"`, I can access the `window` property(?) of it, such as `tell application "System Events" to get window of process "TextEdit"`. (Note that `window` is a list, apparently).

What I want is to query the Object Specifier in some way that will show me which things (properties?), like `window`, are available in the object.  In Python, for example, this could be done using `dir(object_name)`.  Is there an equivalent in Applescript?

I've tried the following two approaches but these, while providing useful lists, do not achieve the goal since they do not return `window` like desired in the example.

`tell application "System Events" to get properties of process "TextEdit"`

`tell application "System Events" to get attributes of process "TextEdit"`

I am looking for something in a similar style which would return `window` and the other properties(?) like `window`.  How can I call such a query in Applescript code?

Also, what precisely is the `window of process "TextEdit"` here?  Is it a `property`? An `attribute`? Something else?  Is there an easy way to answer that question within the Applescript Editor, such as perhaps by interpreting the blue-italics display of the returned `window` object? Does that appearance have significance for distinguishing between properties, attributes, etc?  (What does 'etc' include here, specifically and using correct vocabulary, is part of my question..)

Answer (score 1):

In AppleScript

- `Properties` are *leaf* items like `name`, `identifier`.
- `Elements` are *node* items like `attributes`, `windows`, `documents`.

However `element` is not a part of the standard AppleScript terminology.

If the application is scriptable (which TextEdit is) you get a scripting dictionary to access the **application elements and properties**.

If the application is not scriptable you can access the **UI properties and elements** of the application process via `System Events`.

The AppleScript dictionary of an application contains all information about the available elements, properties, commands / events, enumerations and value types. In Script Editor press <kbd>⇧⌘O</kbd> and select the dictionary.

A more sophisticated – and expensive – tool is [Script Debugger](http://latenightsw.com) which provides a terminology browser. For professional script developing it's indispensable.

Comment: Script Debugger is worth every penny.